# Create an array of hashes in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create an array of hashes in javascript. In other words, I want to do the following thing

```
 var messages = new Array;
 messages['info'].push(["info message1", "info message2", "info message3"]);  
 messages['error'].push(["error message1", "error message2", "error message3"]);
```

and then iterate through each key. But it gives me an error `"Cannot call method 'push' of undefined"`

How can I do it?

Comment: What is the error you got?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access the property `info` of `messages`, which does not exists, hence its value is `undefined`. You are then trying to treat it as an array by calling `.push`. That won't work.

I think what you actually want is to assign the arrays to each of those properties:

```
var messages = {};
messages['info'] = ["info message1", "info message2", "info message3"];  
messages['error'] = ["error message1", "error message2", "error message3"];
// or
// messages.info = ["info message1", "info message2", "info message3"];
// ...
```

Only use arrays with numeric keys. Use plain objects for string keys.

Now that `messages.info` is defined *and* as in array, you can add new messages to it:

```
messages.info.push('some new message');
```

---

[Learn more about objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Comment: +1 This is probably what OP needs, even if the lack of described purpose makes it a little unsure.

Comment: I believe this is what OP meant

Answer (score 2):

You also have to create the arrays in the main array/object :

```
var messages = []; // you probably shoudln't have an arrray but {}
messages['info'] = [];
messages['info'].push(["info message1", "info message2", "info message3"]);
```

Comment: @FelixKling You're right, this probably isn't the most useful. I'll upvote your question :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to create an empty array before you can call `.push()` on it.  In addition, arrays are designed for numeric index access.  If you want to access `messages` by property names like 'info', then you should use an object instead of an array:

```
 var messages = {};
 messages['info'] = [];
 messages['info'].push(["info message1", "info message2", "info message3"]);  
 messages['error'] = [];
 messages['error'].push(["error message1", "error message2", "error message3"]);
```

or a little more concise:

```
 var messages = {};
 messages['info'] = ["info message1", "info message2", "info message3"];
 messages['error'] = ["error message1", "error message2", "error message3"];
```

Answer (score 1):

just create the array before adding to it:

```
messages['info'] = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't define `messages['info']` or `messages['error']` before using it. Initialize it first. Also, arrays should not be used to store key/value mappings, use a plain object for that.

```
var messages = new Object;
messages['info'] = new Array;
messages['info'].push("info message1", "info message2", "info message3");
messages['error'] = new Array;  
messages['error'].push("error message1", "error message2", "error message3");
```

Note that you had another error in your original code, namely you were passing an array to `.push()`, which would result in an *array of arrays of arrays*.

Or using object and array literals (recommended):

```
var messages = {};
messages['info'] = ["info message1", "info message2", "info message3"];
messages['error'] = ["error message1", "error message2", "error message3"];
```